# FT231XS RX TX voltage

Tags: uart, ftdi

In the FT231XS is possible to change the rx/tx logic levels voltage? For example, change between 3.3V to 5V?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to know whether you can interface the chip with 5V logic.  There is no issue with interfacing it to 3.3V logic as it is.

The chip runs off 5V, but has an internal voltage regulator to generate 3.3V which is output on the pin 3V3OUT.  This is typically tied to the VCCIO pin, which sets the logic level at 3.3V.  You cannot run VCCIO any higher than 3.63V.

The logic inputs are tolerant of 5V, so there is no problem connecting a Rx line using 5V logic to the chip.  The issue is whether a VCCIO of 3.3V will be enough to drive the input to your other circuitry from the Tx output.

TTL has a minimum of 2V, so that is not a problem.  CMOS though generally has a minimum high level of 2/3 VCC, which in this case would be 2/3 of 5V which is 3.3V.  So you would be right on the line, which is not good.  (Check the minimum high input voltage of whatever you are connecting Tx to, if it is more than 0.6*VCC, you will need to boost VCCIO as described in the next paragraph>)

So if you need to output to CMOS inputs, you should provide 3.6V externally to the VCCIO pin, instead of tying it to 3V3OUT.  This will adequately drive CMOS inputs.  To do this you will need to add an LDO regulator (such as the [TPS7201QP](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps72.pdf)) on the 5V line to drop it down to 3.6V.

Comment: Yes but i didnt find the answer